# How does "__getitem__" call "__missing__" for dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

There is a user defined dict class (subclass dict) to covert non-string keys to str on lookup, such as, `d.get('2') returns 'two', d.get(4) returns 'four'.`

```
class StrKeyDict0(dict): 
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, str):
            raise KeyError(key)
        return self[str(key)]

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default
```

In the `__missing__` function, it raises KeyError when the key is str. This is to avoid infinite recursion when `str(k)` is not an existing key, since `self[str(key)]` would call `__getitem__` passing that str key, which in turn would call `__missing__` again.

My question is, what if the input key is a string already? Say for `d.get('2')`, it would `try self['2']`, which would call `__getitem__` and then `__missing__`. Why the KeyError is not triggered for this case?

I guess it depends on how `__missing__` method is called in `__getitem__` in the parent class `dict`? If `__missing__` check is triggered after trying to get the value in `__getitem__` , then the error will not be triggered?

Answer (score 0):

> Why the KeyError is not triggered for this case?

It is, but you caught it and returned default:

```
    try:
        return self[key]
    except KeyError:    # <---- KeyError raised in __missing__ caught here
        return default
```